# How to exclude files from Dojo's Build System?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, dojo-build

I'm following the [official documentation page about the topic](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/build/buildSystem.html#trees-dirs-and-files) but I cannot configure it to ignore `.txt` files.

I have a `all.profile.js` on the root of my project:

```
var profile = (function(){
    return {
        basePath: "./",
        releaseDir: "../web",
        action: "release",
        layerOptimize: "closure",
        optimize: "closure",
        cssOptimize: "comments",
        mini: true,
        stripConsole: "all",

        packages: [
            { name: "myapp", location: "myapp" }
        ]
    };
})();
```

And this is the `package.json` inside the folder `myapp`:

```
{
    "dojoBuild": "myapp.profile.js",
    "name": "my-app",
    "description": "This is My App",
    "version": "1.0",
    "main": "src"
}
```

And this is the `myapp.profile.js` also inside the folder `myapp`:

```
var profile = (function(){
    return {
        // don't need to do anything on the 'test' folder so don't define it on the trees.
        trees: [
            ["libs","libs",/txt$/], // ignore .txt files -> DOESN'T WORK!
            ["src","src",/txt$/]    // ignore .txt files -> DOESN'T WORK!
        ],
        resourceTags: {
            test: function(filename, mid){
                console.log("[test] filename: ",filename);
                return filename.indexOf("test/") !== -1;
            },
            copyOnly: function(filename, mid){
                //console.log("[copyOnly] mid: ",mid);
                return false;
            },
            miniExclude: function (filename, mid) {
                console.log("[miniExclude] filename: ",filename);
                return mid in {
                    'myapp/myapp.profile': 1,
                    'myapp/package.json': 2
                } || mid.indexOf(".txt") !== -1; // .txt are not ignored so exclude them...
            },
            amd: function(filename, mid) {
                //console.log("[amd] mid: ",mid);
                // myapp is not AMD but this will 'convert' it
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Finally, this is the folder structure:

```
web_dev/
-- myapp/
---- libs/
---- src/
---- test/
---- myapp.profile.js
---- package.json
-- all.profile.js
```

The build tool runs fine, it reads and process all files but the `.txt` files are still on the release dir.

Please let me know if you spot any mistakes on my logic or how I'm configuring the build system. I'm using Dojo 1.9.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong with my initial scenario but here are the changes that I made to have the desired result:

1. Move the `trees` declaration from the `myapp.profile.js` to 
   `all.profile.js` inside the 'myapp' package definition.
2. Instead of specifying the root of the trees, check
   everything and exclude accordingly: `[".", ".",
   /(\/\.)|(~$)|(test|txt)/]`

The final `all.profile.js`:

```
var profile = {
    basePath: "./",
    releaseDir: "../web",
    releaseName: "built",
    action: "release",
    layerOptimize: "closure",
    optimize: "closure",
    cssOptimize: "comments",
    mini: true,
    stripConsole: "all",

    packages: [
        {
            name: "myapp",
            location: "myapp",
            trees: [
                // don't bother with .hidden, tests and txt.
                [".", ".", /(\/\.)|(~$)|(test|txt)/]
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

If anyone can pin point exactly what I was doing wrong, please share.